# Как с помощью рефлексии получить зн экземпляра внутри объекта Java?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Мне нужно записать все значения полей в файл, но не получается это сделать, если в классе есть экземпляр другого класса.

Как это можно сделать на примере класса `MyClass`?

В частности, не могу понять, откуда взять объект:

```
MyClass2 mc = new MyClass2("cl2", 10, 10);
```

если он лежит внутри класса, чтобы по аналогии вытащить его зн полей.

```
public void write(Class cl, Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException, FileNotFoundException {
        writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        if (!verifyAnnotationSerializ(cl)) throw new RuntimeException("Не поддерживает аннотацию Serializable");
        Field[] fields = cl.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            if (!writer(f, obj)) {
//                write(f.getType(), obj);
            };
        }
        writer.close();
    }

private boolean writer(Field f, Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException, FileNotFoundException {
    switch (f.getType().getSimpleName()) {
        case "String": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.get(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "double": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getDouble(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "int": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getInt(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "float": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getFloat(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "short": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getShort(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "char": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getChar(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "long": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getLong(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "byte": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getByte(obj)));
            return true;
        }
        case "boolean": {
            writeInFile(String.valueOf(f.getBoolean(obj)));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void writeInFile(String str) throws FileNotFoundException {
    writer.println(str);
}

    public class MyClass {
        String str;
        int x = 0;
        double y;
        MyClass2 mc = new MyClass2("cl2", 10, 10);

        public MyClass(String str, int x, double y) {
            this.str = str;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что значит сокращение "зн", не подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто. Если поле не примитивное, то его нужно прогнать через ваш метод write, например так:

```
// проходимся по всем полям объекта
private Field[] write(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        writer(field.get(object));
    }

    return fields;
}

// записываем примитивные поля в файл, либо дальше раскрываем
private void writer(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {

    if (object.getClass().isPrimitive() || object instanceof String) {
        writeInFile(String.valueOf(object));
    }
    else {
        write(object);
    }
}
```

По поводу откуда взять класс `MyClass2`, то думаю нужно просто скопировать MyClass и переименовать, конструкторы совпадают.